# Django. Обработать исключение "password_mismatch"

Tags: django, пароль

Реализуется простая операция смены пароля пользователя в Django. При этом Django бросает исключение

> KeyError "password_mismatch"

в определении параметров исключения в `clean_new_password2(self)` при проверке формы `pwd_form.is_valid()`. Непонятно, как решить проблему этого исключения средствами формы, унаследованной от встроенной `PasswordChangeForm`:

**метод Django:**

```
def clean_new_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')
        if password1 and password2:
            if password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['password_mismatch'], …
                    code='password_mismatch',
                )
        password_validation.validate_password(password2, self.user)
        return password2
```

**forms.py**

```
class PasswordChangeCustomForm(PasswordChangeForm): 
    error_css_class = 'red' 
    error_messages = {'password_incorrect': "Старый пароль неверен. Попробуйте ещё раз!"}
    # поля формы
    old_password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control'}), error_messages={ 'required': 'Требуется ввести старый пароль!'}) 
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control'}), error_messages={ 'required': 'Введите новый пароль!'}) 
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control'}), error_messages={ 'required': 'Введите новый пароль ещё раз!'})
```

**views.py**

```
def change_password(request):
    ''' Обработка формы смены пароля пользователя. '''
    user = User.objects.filter(username=request.user).first()
    pwdChangeResult = ''
    pwd_form = PasswordChangeCustomForm(user, request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if pwd_form.is_valid(): # ошибка "password_mismatch"
            old_password = pwd_form.cleaned_data['old_password']
            new_password1 = pwd_form.cleaned_data['new_password1']
            new_password2 = pwd_form.cleaned_data['new_password2']
            if check_password(old_password, user.password): 
                if new_password1 == new_password2:  
                    user.set_password(new_password2)
                    user.save()
                    pwdChangeResult = 'Пароль успешно изменён!'
                else:
                    pwdChangeResult = 'Новые пароли не совпадают!'
            else:
                pwdChangeResult = 'Старый пароль неверен!' 

    context = {'pwd_form': pwd_form, 'pwdChangeResult': pwdChangeResult, 'error': pwd_form.errors} 
    return context
```

Похоже, что и во view `change_password` проверку введённых паролей дублировать не нужно или, всё-таки, какие-то необходимы?

Comment: Впрочем, на самом деле это мало на что влияет, ведь в вашем словаре `error_messages` и вправду нет никакого `password_mismatch`, так что ошибка вполне логична

Comment: Предполагается, что этот словарь должен быть унаследован от встроенной формы.

Comment: Вы его перезатёрли своим словарём, так что от наследования ничего не осталось

Comment: Ага, вижу подвох, словарь переопределен! )

Comment: Для примера посмотрите, как реализовано наследование словаря в самом PasswordChangeForm: https://github.com/django/django/blob/9ef4a18dbe71f538a9ef8c39111ae2f0b62eb90b/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L373-L381

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку, как раз задался этим вопросом о содержании данного словаря!